# Dividing a whole number by another fraction that includes a Root?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, roots

The question is simplifying $$\frac{9}{\frac{9\sqrt{97}}{97}}$$ The program has told me the answer found is $\sqrt{97}$, but I cannot figure out how this answer is found. I also do not have a calculator that shows roots in the solution, so I need to figure this out myself. I have searched all over the internet for video explanations on dividing a rational by a whole number and can't find anything. I am studying for a placement test after taking a gap year so I figure there's some cancelling I might of forgot, or a forgotten strategy here.

Comment: maybe this helps: $\frac{\sqrt{x}}{x} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$

Comment: Thanks for the reply, gap years are bad. Hm, that seems very familiar. Well, If I am looking at this right I can use this rule to get 9/(9/​√97)? I still don't know where I can take this to get ​√97 as my answer though.

Comment: Nevermind, huge brain fart, got it haha thanks.

Answer (score 3):

$$\frac{\not9}{\cfrac{\not9\sqrt{97}}{97}}=\frac{97}{\sqrt{97}}=\sqrt{97}.$$

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this $$\frac 9{\left(\frac{9\sqrt{97}}{97}\right)}\cdot\frac {\sqrt {97}}{\sqrt {97}}=\frac {9\sqrt {97}}{\left(\frac {9\cdot 97}{97}\right)}=\frac {9\sqrt{97}
}{9}=\sqrt {97}$$

Answer (score 0):

$\color{green}{\text{This is why we multiply by the reciprocal when dividing fractions}}$
$$\frac{9}{\frac{9\sqrt{97}}{97}}=\frac{\frac{9}{1}}{\frac{9\sqrt{97}}{97}}=\frac{\frac{9}{1}}{\frac{9\sqrt{97}}{97}}\cdot\color{green}{\frac{\frac{97}{9\sqrt{97}}}{\frac{97}{9\sqrt{97}}}}=\frac{\frac{9\cdot97}{9\sqrt{97}}}{\color{green}{1}}=\frac{9\cdot97}{9\cdot\sqrt{97}}=\frac{\sqrt{97}^2}{\sqrt{97}}=\sqrt{97}$$

Answer (score 0):

Why is everyone here complicating this... 
Here is a straightforward answer:
$$
\frac{9}{\frac{9\sqrt{97}}{97}} = 9 \div \frac{9\sqrt{97}}{97} = 9 \times \frac {97} {9\sqrt{97}} = \frac {97}{\sqrt {97}} = \frac {(\sqrt {97}) ^2 } {\sqrt {97}} = \sqrt {97} 
$$

No reciprocal multiplying or confusing  shortcuts, straight to the point :3